# Convert Nested JSON to Flat JSON using jolt Spec based on multiple inputs (if else)

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I need to convert the nested json to flat json by given type of input, if its flat json or nested json gives output as flat json respectively. I haven't seen any correct resource related to the this topic. I given the inputs and outputs below.

I am having some trouble with converting the nested JSON to flat JSON, and didn't get any closer as to what is mentioned problem. I need to transform a JSON structure by using a JOLT spec. I use https://jolt-demo.appspot.com to test the following below. Help me, how can i get the expected out, with this code

**Input-1:**

```json
{
  "MessageType": "CREATION",
  "Number": "123",
  "Status": "created sucessfully",
  "StopSequence": "1",
  "Code": [
    {
      "CodeName": "ABC",
      "ShortDescription": "short description about ABC",
      "TimeImpact": 234,
      "Rank": 1
    },
    {
      "ReasonCodeName": "XYZ",
      "ShortDescription": "short description about ABC",
      "TimeImpact": 123,
      "Rank": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

**Input-2:**

```
{
    "MessageType": "UPDATE",
    "Number": "345",
    "PNumber": "P123",
    "Status": "updated sucessfully",
    "StopSequence": "2",
    "Id": 1234,
    "LNumber": "34565",
    "DeviceID": "7645235",
    "Timestamp": "2015-10-01T16:00:00-05:00",
    "Timezone": "US/New_York",
    "TimezoneShortName": "EST",
    "Unlocode": "XXXX",
}
```

**Expected Output-1 if input 1 passes:**

```json
[
  {
    "MessageType": "CREATION",
    "Number": "123",
    "Status": "created sucessfully",
    "StopSequence": "1",
    "Code": "1",
    "CodeName": "ABC",
    "ShortDescription": "short description about ABC",
    "TimeImpact": 234,
    "CodeRank": 1
  },
  {
    "MessageType": "CREATION",
    "Number": "123",
    "Status": "created sucessfully",
    "StopSequence": "1",
    "Code": "2",
    "ReasonCodeName": "XYZ",
    "ShortDescription": "short description about ABC",
    "TimeImpact": 123,
    "Rank": 2
  }
]
```

**Expected Output-2 if input 2 passes:**

```
{
    "MessageType": "UPDATE",
    "PNumber": "P123",
    "Status": "updated sucessfully",
    "StopSequence": "2",
    "Id": 1234,
    "Timestamp": "2015-10-01T16:00:00-05:00",
    "Timezone": "US/New_York",
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to repeat as much as the number of objects of the **`Code`** array. So, walk through by them as picking the related values from the out of the array such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Code": {
        "*": {
          "@(2,MessageType)": "[&1].MessageType", // "@(2,MessageType)" means going up the tree 2 levels to reach the position of "MessageType" , [&1] means combining the values as array of objects depending on the indexes of the array 
          "@(2,Number)": "[&1].Number",
          "@(2,Status)": "[&1].Status",
          "@(2,StopSequence)": "[&1].StopSequence",
          "@(0,Rank)": "[&1].Code", // to copy the values of the "Rank" to "Code"
          "*": "[&1].&"
        }
      },
      "MessageT*|PNu*|St*|Id|Times*|Timezone": "&"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Hi @Barbaros Özhan. Thank you for the response. I've added one case condition. Please lookin to. I need one jolt spec which will handle both the condition

Comment: @VamsiKumar_gudala I've added the desired condition as well